# x-value mouseover tooltip d3 - editing the tooltip style and text

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I have been trawling for a solution to a problem with how to display/alter the text in a tooltip for d3js when you use the closest x-value to get the mouseover event.

In [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015), the text for the tooltip becomes half hidden/invisible when you hover to the far right of the screen, whereas this doesn't happen when you use the basic d3 tooltip provided in examples.  Also, I can't figure out how to get a line break in that text (i've tried using html line breaks to no avail).

Can anyone shed light on how to counter this problem?

Comment: That's a SVG text element, it doesn't accept HTML line breaks (like `br`).

Comment: Yes-  I understand that - as another thread here covered this issue. However, when I use the regular d3 tooltip, you can insert line breaks like br.  IS this also a text SVG element?

Comment: What is a "regular" d3 tooltip? D3 has no tooltips. My favourite way if creating tooltips is using divs

Comment: Like in this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) - the tooltip is done as a div. , I have tried incorporating the same method in the example mentioned in my original question to no avail!

Comment: Yes, that's the way I normally do. Did you remember to set the div position as absolute?

Comment: Yes - I have tried this and it didn't work!please see my fiddle here: (https://jsfiddle.net/ws1a2wt0/)

Answer (score 0):

Try foxTooltip.js.  It automatically adjusts the tooltip position to account for screen boundaries.  You can also modify the content dynamically.

https://github.com/MichaelRFox/foxToolTip.js

Comment: I am hoping to find a solution without using another JS library-  but I will look into this - thanks for the suggstion